# Strange values returned when looping through array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

```
$rows = getChallengeList();
error_log(print_r($rows, 1));
?>
<table border="1">
    <tr><th>ID</th><th>Title</th><th>Description</th></tr>
    <?php foreach ($rows as $row): ?>
        <?php foreach($row as $chal): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $chal['loyalty_challenges_id']; ?></td>
            <td><?= $chal['title']; ?></td>
            <td><?= $chal['description']; ?></td>
        </tr>    
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

The error_log returns this:

```
[11-Jan-2013 10:44:27] Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [loyalty_challenges_id] => 1
            [title] => New Customer Special
            [description] => Reward new customers with a free order of breadsticks after placing their second order during their first 30 days 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [loyalty_challenges_id] => 2
            [title] => Frequent Flyer Special
            [description] => Reward long-time customers who order often with a free pizza
        )

)
```

But the values rendered by the loop look like this:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr><th>ID</th><th>Title</th><th>Description</th></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>    
    <tr>
        <td>N</td>
        <td>N</td>
        <td>N</td>
    </tr>    
    <tr>
        <td>R</td>
        <td>R</td>
        <td>R</td>
    </tr>    
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>    
    <tr>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>F</td>
    </tr>    
    <tr>
        <td>R</td>
        <td>R</td>
        <td>R</td>
    </tr>    
</table>
```

Any idea what would cause that? It's been a while since I've worked with straight php, rather than CMS's that have their own array processing functions.

Comment: Please stop using short tags.

Comment: You need just one `foreach`.

Comment: @njk - I was taught that it was preferable to do that if you were going to have a lot of HTML with php values interspersed than to echo out hundreds of lines of html just so you can stay inside a single php tag.

Comment: @EmmyS Check this out: [Are PHP short tags acceptable to use?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/200666/1134705)

Comment: @Asok - according to that answer, "As ThiefMaster mentions in the comments, as of PHP 5.4, <?= ... ?> tags are supported everywhere, regardless of shorttags settings. This should mean they're safe to use in portable code but that does mean there's then a dependency on PHP 5.4+". Not an issue - we own all our servers, so we have complete control over them.

Comment: @EmmyS +1 Yes, I was just giving you more information. I wasn't making any suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have one loop too much:

```
$rows = getChallengeList();
error_log(print_r($rows, 1));
?>
<table border="1">
    <tr><th>ID</th><th>Title</th><th>Description</th></tr>
    <?php foreach ($rows as $chal): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $chal['loyalty_challenges_id']; ?></td>
            <td><?= $chal['title']; ?></td>
            <td><?= $chal['description']; ?></td>
        </tr>    
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Explanation: when using $chal['loyalty_challenges_id'];  against the $chal string value, the 'loyalty_challenges_id' value is cast to a numeric, giving 0, so it displays the character at offset 0 of the string, the first character in the string

Comment: Thanks. I could swear I already tried that and got empty strings back, but I guess not.

Answer (score 1):

You need just one `foreach`:

```
<?php foreach ($rows as $row): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['loyalty_challenges_id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['title']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['description']; ?></td>
    </tr>    
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**What's happening ?**

When you loop thrue `$chal` you loop thrue each key, and when you try to access
`$chal['loyalty_challenges_id'];`

is the same of

`$rows[0]['loyalty_challenges_id']['loyalty_challenges_id']`

which is translated to

`$rows[0]['loyalty_challenges_id'][0]`

That's why you get the first letter on each row.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
<?php foreach ($rows as $row): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['loyalty_challenges_id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['title']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['description']; ?></td>
    </tr>    
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php foreach($row as $chal): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?= $chal['loyalty_challenges_id']; ?></td>
        <td><?= $chal['title']; ?></td>
        <td><?= $chal['description']; ?></td>
    </tr>    
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

This foreach is unneeded. Remove it, and use `$row['loyalty_challenges_id']` etc.